# awk to remove cr/lf or fields until total fields

Tags: awk

I have a file

```
1|2|3|4
a|b|c|d
1|2
3|4
a|
b|
c|
d|
```

The file should have 4 fields to load into a database. The file may have cr, lf, or end of line characters.

What I want to see as output is

```
1|2|3|4
a|b|c|d
1|23|4
a|b|c|d
```

I have tried

```
BEGIN {FS="|";break_flag = 0;field_count=4}
{
#print NF      
delc=gsub(/\|/,"|",$0)
print delc 
if (NF == 4 )
{
print $0
}
else if (delc != 3)
{
#gsub("\"","")
gsub(/\r/,"")
printf("%s|",$0)
}
}
```

What I want is that if the line does not have 4 fields, continue reading until you get 4 fields and print them without cr, lf etc only | as the field separator

Thanks,

Comment: But don't you want to see your output as `1|2|3|4 a|b|c|d 1|2|3|4 a|b|c|d` then?

Comment: Update your question to: a) Describe the alorigthm that leads to the third line of output only having 3 fields: `1|23|4`; b) Describe the algorithm that tells us that the "4" at the end of input line 1 and the "a" at the start of input line 2 should not be combined into a single output field "4a", unlike the way "2" and "3" are joined into "23"; c) State whether or not you can have an input line that has 5 or more fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
awk -f f.awk input.txt
```

where `f.awk` is

```
{
    sub(/[[:blank:]]*$/,"")
    ss=(NR==1)?$0: (ss "|" $0)
}
END {
    gsub(/\|\|/,"|",ss)
    n=split(ss,a,"|")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i+=4)
        for (j=0; j<4; j++)
           printf "%s%s",a[i+j],(j<3)?"|":ORS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A gnu awk version (due to the RS)

```
awk '$1=$1 {printf "%s" (NR%4?"|":"\n"),$0}' RS="[|\n]" file
1|2|3|4
a|b|c|d
1|2|3|4
a|b|c|d
```